# KendoUI for AnfularJS Grid toolbar custom button swatch visibility

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I need to add custom buttons to a Kendo Grid toolbar and switch visibility of each other by clicking an another one (e.g. Button1 click hides Button1 and shows Button2, Button2 click hides Button2 and shows Button1).

I'm able to add these buttons but I can't change their visibility.

My code:

```
<div kendo-grid="grid" k-toolbar="toolbar" k-options="options">
</div>
```

```
class customGrid implements ng.IDirective {
    public restrict = 'A';
    public templateUrl = 'customGrid.directive.html';
    public scope = {
        options: '=',
        grid: '='
    };

    constructor() {
    }

    public link = (scope) => {
        scope.toolbarItems = [
            { 
                name: 'play', 
                iconClass: 'fa fa-play', 
                handler: (toolbar: any) => { 
                    //visibility switch here
                }
            },
            { 
                name: 'pause', 
                iconClass: 'fa fa-pause', 
                handler: (toolbar: any) => { 
                    //visibility switch here
                }
            }];

        const toolbar: any[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < scope.toolbarItems.length; i++) {
            toolbar.push({
                template: `<a ng-click="toolbarItems[${i}].handler()" class="k-button k-button-icontext" href="##"><i class="${scope.toolbarItems[i].iconClass}"></i> ${scope.toolbarItems[i].text}</a>`
            });
        }

        scope.toolbar = toolbar;
    }
```

I can manipulate directly to the DOM but maybe it is possible to do the same using angularJS?

[Live Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/oqinIYIW)

P.S. This is just a sample, in real project "toolbarItems" is an directive's argument and their count can be different.

Comment: can you create a demo for the same

Comment: Update the demo https://dojo.telerik.com/oqinIYIW

Comment: Hi Sergey was your issue fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated dojo for the same. Instead of having separate button you can have one button and change/toggle their css class based on the need.

https://dojo.telerik.com/@amitdwivedi/ajeVoXUf

Hope this solves your purpose.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions" k-toolbar="toolbar">
        </kendo-grid>


    </div>
</div>
<script>
    angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
        .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
          $scope.toolbarItems = [

            { 
                name: 'pause', 
                iconClass: 'fa fa-play', 
                handler: ($event) => { 
                    //visibility switch here
                  if(event.srcElement.className == 'fa fa-pause')
                    event.srcElement.className = "fa fa-play"
                    else
                    event.srcElement.className = "fa fa-pause" 

                }
            }];

        var toolbar = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.toolbarItems.length; i++) {
            toolbar.push({
                template: `<a ng-click="toolbarItems[${i}].handler()" class="k-button k-button-icontext" href="##"><i class="${$scope.toolbarItems[i].iconClass}"></i></a>`
            });
        }

        $scope.toolbar = toolbar;

            $scope.mainGridOptions = {
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                    }
                },
                sortable: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: "FirstName",
                    title: "First Name",
                    width: "120px"
                    },{
                    field: "LastName",
                    title: "Last Name",
                    width: "120px"
                    },{
                    field: "Country",
                    width: "120px"
                    },{
                    field: "City",
                    width: "120px"
                    },{
                    field: "Title"
                }]
            };

        })
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is pretty nice. I will use this.